# Drop column on declarative schema not working as expected

Tags: magento2.3.0, declarative-schema

I was playing on Magento 2.3 with [Declarative Schema](https://magento-devdocs.github.io/devdocs-for-tests/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html), and everything works very well when I added a new column do `db_schema.xml` and did a `setup:upgrade`.

However, when removing a column node from XML and performing `setup:upgrade`, the column was not removed.

I also tried with `--safe-mode=0`, adding `disabled="true"`, flushing cache before, etc, but the column is still there.

**Am I missing something?**

Comment: Please share the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to regenerate whitelist for your module every time you delete something in your **`db_schema.xml`**

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/migration-commands.html#create-whitelist